# Puppeteer Unhandled Rejected at: Promise - Why exception?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless-browser

I am new to both Puppeteer and JavaScript. I am trying to automate some simple tasks, only that the elements appear within iframes - but I have resolved this. What I am unclear about is the exception thrown when I uncomment `await browser.close()`.

My code:

```
const baseUrl = "https://test-environment.com/ABH2829.html?token=dhdj7s8383937hndkeie8j3jebd";
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const clickClothingButton = async () => {

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            slowMo: 250,
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
        process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
           console.error('Unhandled Rejected at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
           browser.close();
        });
        await page.goto(baseUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
         const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 3000});
        await page.waitForSelector('.widget-title');
        const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');
        const clothingButton = await frame.$('#clothing-button');
        clothingButton.click();
        await navigationPromise;
        await browser.close();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};

clickClothingButton();
```

Now this runs fine, but I always get the following:

```
Unhandled Rejected at: Promise Promise {
<rejected> Error: TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 3000ms exceeded
```

If I try to just:

```
await browser.close();
```

Then it barfs with:

```
Unhandled Rejected at: Promise Promise {
<rejected> { Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
```

What's the best way of handling this gracefully, and why can't I just close the browser? Bear in mind I'm still learning about Promises and the contracts that must be fulfilled for them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the site you are appearing to access requires authentication.

[image: Authentication Required]

You can use [`page.authenticate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageauthenticatecredentials) to provide credentials for the HTTP authentication:

```
await page.authenticate({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
});
```

Additionally, the `timeout` you set for [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) is only `3000` ms (3 seconds), while the default is `30000` ms (30 seconds), so if it takes longer than the set amount of time to load the page, you are going to receive a [`TimeoutError`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-timeouterror).

I would strongly recommend allowing at least the default maximum navigation time of 30 seconds for the navigation to occur. You can use the `timeout` option in `page.waitForNavigation()` or use [`page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaultnavigationtimeouttimeout).

Lastly, [`elementHandle.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) `clothingButton.click()`:

```
await clothingButton.click();
```

Comment: Thank you Grant - very much appreciated.  I'm afraid I gave you some extra work to do - that's not my real URL, I was obfuscating it for security ;)  Sorry about that - but everything else helped me a lot